# Valid extensions for the upload field on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to make a form to upload a CSV file. I get the following error when I try to use the form item below:

> Only files with the following extensions are allowed: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp.

```
  $form['data_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Data File'),
    '#description' => t('CSV file to upload.'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'),
      'file_validate_size' => array(32*1024*1024),
    ),
  );
```

How can I let a CSV file pass through the validator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it with the following code in the form validation hook.

```
function mymodule_myform_validate($form, $form_state) {
  $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'));
  $file = file_save_upload('zipdata_file', $validators);
  ...
}
```

Comment: That helps thanks :)  <br/><br/>

For `Drupal 7` This Links https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions/7
   and  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate/7

can help

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [The forms API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#comment-15349) this comment explains how to do it.

I can't exactly test it out, but possibly something like this

```
  $form['data_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Data File'),
    '#description' => t('CSV file to upload.'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'csv'),
      'file_validate_size' => array(32*1024*1024),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I don't see your file_validate_extensions implementation over there.

Comment: $form['file']['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0] = 'png jpg gif pdf';      It was just a few lines up the page.

Comment: You edited your post though.  you had array('0' => array('csv')).  What you have now is exactly what my original version creates.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it would automatically go to index 0 of the array. So it would be the same thing you originally posted. I just edited it again. If that doesn't work, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your form function

```
// don't forget this line
$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

$form['container']['csv_file'] = array(
'#type' => 'file' ,  
'#title' => t('csv FILE') , 
'#description' => t('insert your csv file here') , 
) ;
```

Your validate function

```
function _your_function_validate($form, $form_state) {
$extensions = 'csv' ; 
$validators = array(
 'file_validate_extensions' => array($extensions),
);
// if the file not uploaded or the extension is wrong set error
if(!file_save_upload('csv_file', $validators)) { // cvs_file is the form name
  form_set_error('csv_file', 'Please select the csv file') ;    
}else{ 
// now the form is uploaded lets make another validation for extension
  $file = file_save_upload('csv_file', $validators, file_directory_path()) ; 

// another validator for the extension
if($file->filemime != 'text/csv' ) {
 form_set_error('csv_file', 'Extensions Allowed : csv') ;       
}       
}       
}
```

Comment: Note that in D7, you don't need the enctype attribute in the form. Drupal automatically adds it for you for file fields.